# mongodb unable to find match

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
 Enroll.updateOne(
      {
        "reviewers._id": userID,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "reviewers.$.scores": req.body.scores,
        },
      },
      (errUpdate, resultUpdate) => {
        if (errUpdate) {
          return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: errUpdate });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: resultUpdate });
        }
      }
    );
```

I'm new to mongodb. Above is a function within an api that is used to update certain data.
The schema of Enroll would look like this:

```
[
 {
  _id: xxxxx,
  otherdata: xxxx,
  reviewers: [ { _id: xxxx, otherdata: xxxx } , { _id: xxxx2, otherdata: xxxx2 } ]
 },
 {
 second enroll item...
 }
]
```

but when I called the api, it returns n:0 which indicates no match is found. Am I missing some steps here?

Comment: Can you print `userID` and make sure the type matches with the value stored in the database? (string vs ObjectId)

Comment: i have converted the userID to mongo object id through const userID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.userID);